# Can I have the same login name in both databases on one SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql-server

I have two databases on a SQL Server 2012 instance. Can I have the same login name in both and one at the security level? Meaning can I have login A in DB1 and login A in DB2 and Login A at server level. But DB1 and DB2 connect using the same login A ?

Comment: yes. You create a security user at the server level, and then add the user to the individual database(s) they need access to, with permissions specific to each database. I suggest you read the documentation on the topic, it makes it fairly clear how the structure of SQL logins works. They are not separate logins. There's one server-level login, which then has various permissions, which may include access to specific databases.

Comment: Ok so this means the same loguin can be used differently in diff databases ?

Comment: The **server** has a login - each database then has a **user** based on the login ..... you need to keep those different concepts apart to be clear what you want ... And yes - **one** server-level *login* can be used in *multiple databases* as the basis for each database's user.